# Dynamic height of TextArea in Spring Layout using putConstraint - Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, textarea, panel

I'd like to display notes in the textarea with a dynamic height(some notes are small and other notes are long).
I am retrieving note lines from the textarea to define height in the layout.
I've tried different layouts but it didn't work out. (meaning, different height is set based on the note length correctly but in GUI, all the note heights are distributed evenly.)

This time, I am trying Springlayout to see if it works better but I haven't made much progress. I am not too sure if I am using putConstraint() correctly in my situation.

```
    TextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    ComponentUtils.setComponentText(textArea, note.getDisplayLines());

    int height= textArea.getLineCount(); 

    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    innerPanel.setLayout(layout);
    innerPanel.add(textArea);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textArea,
            5, SpringLayout.NORTH, innerPanel);

    outerPanel.add(innerPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: SpringLayout is hard to use.  It is likely another layout can do what you want and will be easier to work with.  Can you add an ASCII art picture, or simple drawing, to your question to illustrate what you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. yes it was challenging in SpringLayout but I made it work in GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method to solve my own question.
As for the layout, GridBagLayout was a perfect match to create different sizes of height of JTextArea. (When used other layouts, they evenly distributed heights by default which was a problem in my case.)

When you use GridBagLayout, you need to instantiate GradBagConstraints.
With the object, you can call built-in functions; fill, weightx, gridx, gridwith etc to meet your personal needs in the GUI.